# PHP 7 return type hint: Is it downward compatible?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using PHP 7.1.1 to run WordPress. Now, whenever I add functions in the code of my theme or plugins, the IDE tells me to add a return type hint like this:

[image: Example]

I do know how to add it, but I am unsure whether or not return type hints are compatible with older PHP version? Will I run into any problems when using them and, for instance, put the website on a server running PHP 5.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return type declarations are not backward compatible. That will be a syntax error in PHP 5.